# Choosing the right data structure: boolean check vs array .include (performance vs redundancy)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have objects which can have one or more properties assigned. In my particular case, there are a total of 5 different properties.

To simplify things, let's take a basic movie example with 5 different genres which could be assigned to every movie.

I thought of two ways to do that:

- have a boolean for every single property for every single object OR
- have an array with a list of assigned properties for every object

That means:

Option 1:

```
[{id: 1, name: 'some movie 1', comedy: true, thriller: true, drama: true, action: false, adventure: true},
{id: 2, name: 'some movie 2', comedy: false, thriller: true, drama: false, action: false, adventure: false},
{id: 3, name: 'some movie 3', comedy: true, thriller: true, drama: true, action: false, adventure: true},
{id: 4, name: 'some movie 4', comedy: true, thriller: true, drama: true, action: false, adventure: false}, ...]
```

Option 2:

```
[{id: 1, name: 'some movie 1', genre: ['comedy','thriller','drama']},
{id: 2, name: 'some movie 2', genre: ['thriller','drama']},
{id: 3, name: 'some movie 3', genre: ['comedy','thriller','adventure']},
{id: 4, name: 'some movie 4', genre: ['comedy','thriller']}, ...]
```

I want to go with option 2 as it's more compact and doesn't store redundant data (boolean false-values).

However, I am worried about the performance as I have to check the arrays via .include() for the particular property string, while option 1 requires a simple boolean check which is seemingly faster.

So if my statement above is correct, I'm feeling like having to choose between redundancy and performance (please correct if wrong). Is there perhaps a better approach for this, i.e. a different data structure altogether?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need to include the `false` properties in option 1. Just leave them undefined.

Comment: But then I must check if the parameter actually exists, for example via  `if ('comedy' in movieObject === true)`. Wouldn't that be similar to `.include()`?

Comment: Are you prematurely optimizing here, or have you actually run into performance problems? This kind of filtering should ideally be done by the server, either with server-side-rendering or as an API endpoint. The client should not have to deal with such kinds of heavy computation. If you absolutely must do it though, how about doing it with a WebWorker so it runs in a separate thread? You could also run your own JS performance benchmarks to determine the fastest method.

Comment: I agreed with @jered that you may be prematurely optimizing here. Option 2 is clean and easy to understand. If a new genre is introduced then the _shape_ of your `movie` object will not need to change, unlike with Option 1. There are no doubt optimizations that can be applied based on your use case. My advice is to try it first - measure - and assess.

Comment: What does your actual data look like (how many tags, how many entries) and what operations will you need (search for single tags, union of tags, intersection of tags, exclude tags)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to include the `false` properties in option 1. Just leave them `undefined`, which is a [*falsy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value.

```js
const movies = [
  {id: 1, name: 'some movie 1', comedy: true, thriller: true, drama: true, adventure: true},
  {id: 2, name: 'some movie 2', thriller: true},
  {id: 3, name: 'some movie 3', comedy: true, thriller: true, drama: true, adventure: true},
  {id: 4, name: 'some movie 4', comedy: true, thriller: true, drama: true,}
];

const comedies = movies.filter(m => m.comedy);

console.log(comedies);
```

This gets rid of the redundant data, while still allowing for good filtering performance.

Answer (score 0):

have a single genres key with an integer with meaningful binary representation, like flags:

```
comedy  drama   something else  
   1      0            1       === 1 * 2^2 + 0 * 2^1 + 1 === 5
```

you end up:

```
{
    id:1,
    name: "some",
    genre: 5
}
```

to see if this includes comedy, you have to test:

```
(genre ^ 4) === (genre - 4)
```

if you would test to see for drama you would do:

```
(5 ^ 2) === (5 - 2) //false
```

I mean you get the idea, you can also go for shorter bitmasking `genre & 4` , as others pointed out in the comments.Whatever suits your taste

Comment: Like `genre & 4`?

Comment: same, sure, why not

Answer (score -2):

You should not be doing this kind of filtering on the client. Computing big datasets is slow and will block the main browser thread, causing UI stutter and slowdowns. You should set up a server with an API to filter this type of stuff completely independent of the client, so that you can simply query the API and get the filtered data you need. If you are filtering/computing so much data on the client that performance concerns become an issue, *you are probably doing something wrong* in terms of how you've structured your app.

If you absolutely MUST do filtering like this on the client, [I suggest you do it in a WebWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) so that it happens in a background thread and does not block the UI.

Even then, if you decide to do it on the client (WebWorker or not) you are going to run into cross-browser concerns. Every browser potentially implements JavaScript a little differently and has their own quirks. One method may be faster in one browser but slower in another. If you really want to know which method is fastest, you could run some benchmarks to try and figure it out. [Which I went ahead and did here](https://jsperf.com/large-data-filtering).

[image: JSPerf benchmark]

As you can see, there are differences between browsers, because Chrome, FireFox and Safari use different JavaScript engines (V8, SpiderMonkey, and Webkit respectively). Your safest bet would be to pick the most-universally-fast method, which in this case seems to be `Array.includes()` (longer bars are better). It is tied for best performance in Chrome, the most popular browser, with good performance in Firefox and pretty good performance in Safari too.

Conclusion:

1. Built an API for this kind of task if possible
2. If you must do it client-side, use a WebWorker
3. In any case, `Array.includes()` seems to be the best bet

Comment: Not sure who downvoted you really, your post had some useful information for me, +1 from me

Comment: This advice is waaaaaaay too general. There are many cases where the client would be a perfectly acceptable place to filter data, and many volumes of data for which a WebWorker may well be overcomplicated.